# Facebook PHP SDK adding permissions after login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm working on integrating the Facebook PHP SDK into a website I am building, and I have a question (maybe a problem, not sure yet...).

Initially I was planning on setting all the permissions in the initial login to allow my users to post to their feeds/page feeds through my site depending on which route they prefer, BUT I read on the FB SDK pages that requiring permissions at initial login that are not essential at that moment is bad practice.

My question is how do you add more permissions later using the PHP SDK? I scoured the internet for two days now looking for an example, and haven't been able to find one. Maybe I am looking in the wrong places. I don't know. I just haven't had any luck.

My thought is that you check if the permission is set, and if not, log the user in with that permission, and use the new access token. The issue for me is that doing it this way, I will have to write the form data to the session, then call it back when the FB login sequence is done.

Is my thinking correct, or is there a way to do this better? Should I just stack all the permissions right off the bat, or should I do it the way Facebook suggests?

The whole reason that my site is using facebook is to allow users to automatically share their posts (it is an art site) when they upload a piece to the site, instead of uploading a piece then having to go to that piece and click a share button on the page.

Hopefully this rambling makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how do you add more permissions later using the PHP SDK?

Same way, as you asked for the initial permissions:

By calling the login dialog again, with those additional permissions in the `scope`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I didn't know if it was using the login dialog again or what.